# Retrieving Contentful ID in Gatsby GraphQL

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I use graghql to query data from contentful, in gatsby-node.js

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) =>  {
  ...
  const result = await graphql(
    `
      {
        allContentfulArticle(
          sort: { order: DESC, fields: date },
          limit: 2000
        ) {
          totalCount,
          edges {
            node {
              id
              title
              excerpt
              date
              tag
              content{
                content
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
})
```

The returned id in node does not match my contentful entry's id. For example, one return id is `32015820-f327-5085-b5c0-27146850a8f5`, but my entry's id is `2pljYDQAJ8umcV5po5TDK8`

When I use contentful delivery api I can get the correct id, so, what happed? Who changes the id's format? How to get the correct id? The contentful plugin I use is gatsby-source-contentful.

Comment: You're not really specifying anywhere which `id` you'd like to retrieve, at least in the query you're showing above. So perhaps looking at the schema to figure out how to retrieve a specific item would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the GraphiQL explorer on `http://localhost:8000/___graphql` you can see the entire GraphQL schema.

As you can see there are two ID fields for each item: just `id` is the Gatsby ID and `contentful_id` is the Contentful ID. So `contentful_id` is what you're looking for.

[image: GraphiQL explorer contentful schema]

Comment: You are my hero, thank you, I just forget to check http://localhost:8000/___graphql.